# Routinely Retrieving Column from :through Table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, has-many-through, has-many

I have a dictionary database that works for many languages. The structure is like this:

Table: English_words

- id
- word
- wordtype
- grammar

Table: Spanish_words
(same as for English)

Table: French_words
(same as for English)

Table: English_Spanish

- english_id
- spanish_id
- weight_english
- weight_spanish
- use_english_if
- use_spanish_if

The last four columns are for helping my program decide which of the many possible translations are the best suited in a particular context. My English model contains

```
has_many :es_words, :through => :english_spanish, :order => 'weight_english ASC'
```

in order to get the possible Spanish translations in order of preference. Additionally, I later need to do some more complicated filtering based on the rules in the use_.._if columns. So whenever I write "this_word.es_words" to retrieve Spanish translations for an English word, I would like my resulting objects to also contain the use_.._if columns from the joining table. I cannot imagine ever needing just the translations without those columns, so I would like to solve this on a model level rather than in the controller. What is the best way to do it?

(The reason I don't have use_if in the Spanish_words table is that I'm translating multiple languages, and the conditions will vary depending on what language I'm translating from/to)

Answer (score 0):

See [eager loading of associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations) (the "include" method).

Comment: Could you elaborate? I tried "EnglishWord.includes(:use_english_if).first" and it gives an error. Same for "thisword.es_words.includes(:use_english_if).first" and variations on that. The only way I can access the use_english_if column at all is by ignoring my has_many :es_words connection and talking directly to the through table: thisword.english_spanish.first.use_english_if . It's too cumbersome to use often, so I want to extend has_many or create my own function that voids the need to talk to the english_spanish table.